# removesuffix returns error 'str' object has no attribute 'removesuffix'

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to remove the .png part of a filename using remove suffix

`'x.png'.removesuffix('.png')`

But it keeps returning:

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'removesuffix'`

I've tried some other string functions but I keep getting 'str' object has no attribute ' '. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Probably older python version

Comment: I'm using python 3.8.8

Comment: [PEP 616](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0616/), which proposes the `removesuffix` method, was accepted for Python 3.9.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

What are you trying to do?

`removesuffix` is a 3.9+ method in `str`. In previous versions, `str` doesn't have a `removesuffix` attribute:

```
dir(str)
```

If you're not using `3.9`, there's a few ways to approach this. In `3.4+`, you can use `pathlib` to manipulate the suffix if it's a path:

```
import pathlib

pathlib.Path("x.png").with_suffix("")
```

Otherwise, [per the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removesuffix):

```
def remove_suffix(input_string, suffix):
    if suffix and input_string.endswith(suffix):
        return input_string[:-len(suffix)]
    return input_string
```